# Replace text with regular expressions under certain condition

Tags: regex

I need help with Regular Expressions. I need to replace every link that doesn't have this structure: `href="www.domain.com/en/"` with `href="www.domain.com/en/"`

So, if I have this `ref="www.domain.com/something"`> I want to replace it with `href="www.domain.com/en/something"`

Can't this be done with regular expressions?

Comment: Which language / regex engine?

Comment: if you are trying to use pure regexp in html I **do not recommend it**. use a HTML parser instead.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `ref="www.domain.com/` with `ref="www.domain.com/en/`

You don't even need a regular expression for this.

I'm assuming you're just trying to do a search / replace for development purposes. If this is production code, I encourage you to look into HTML parser, such as Jsoup and do a proper parse / traversal / replacement.

---

As pointed out by anubhava, you may want to avoid having `/en/en` in the result.

This can be done with regular expressions and negative lookahead. To say "domain not followed by /en" you use `domain(?!/en)`.

Comment: Wouldn't that turn `<a href="www.domain.com/en/foo">Foo</a>` into `<a href="www.domain.com/en/en/foo">Foo</a>`

Comment: I assumed that `something` could be anything, including `en`. But I'll update the answer slightly.